# Synchronizing two sets of data sampled at different frequencies

Tags: synchronization

I have two different datasets.
Dataset 1 has a frequency of 1000Hz/sec and dataset 2 has a frequency of 50Hz/sec, how can I synchronize the two datasets so that they can be used as training data?

Comment: Hz is the inverse of time so Hz/sec is unit-less. I suppose you mean Hz, not Hz/sec, and that you're talking about the **sampling frequency**, not just *frequency* You need to edit your question with a lot more info. In particular, what is the data representing? Do both datasets represent the same type of data? What is the frequency content (i.e, what frequencies carry the most information) for each dataset? This is important to know if re-sampling is a good option. What language are you using (for reference functions we can provide guidance for)? Once you edit, you'll get closer to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are two different sample rates, this is unlikely to work since both sample rates differ by a factor of 20. Dataset 1 contains frequencies from 0Hz to 25 Hz and Dataset 2 from 0Hz to 500Hz. You can either up-sample Dataset 1, but you end up with 95% of the spectrum being zero or down-sample Dataset 2 losing 95% if the information.

> how can I synchronize the two datasets so that they can be used as training data?

If there is enough mutual information in the 0-25Hz band, you may be able to synchronize them. Much better would be to sample the data sets at a rate that's been properly determined by analyzing the properties of the underlying process/signal

Answer (score 0):

Having one vector sampled at 1000 samples/second, and another sampled at 50 samples/second, both describing the same or a related signal, the standard way to compare them would be to resample either to a common samplerate and possibly alligning them in time.

For efficiency, that might be the minimum of the two. Assuming that you are interested in linear dependencies.